# how to get the value from a key,value form a map reduce job in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd

I am trying to get the value from the map-reduce job i.e. 11 from hinein.

```
(mutuelle,1)
(hinein.,11)
(Pfennig,1)
```

I'm able to print out all the values, but how do I find only the specific ones?

```
val counts = books.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
val MappedRDD = counts.map(word => (word, 1))
val myReducedRDD = MappedRDD.reduceByKey(_ + _)
//myReducedRDD.collect().foreach(println)
val rdd2 = myReducedRDD.map(f => (f))
rdd2.foreach(println)
```

Comment: You probably should have used `reduceByKeyLocally` to generate a local **Scala** `Map` that you can query.

Comment: how would I then query?

Comment: Using any of the operations provided by the `Map`, like `map("key")` or `map.get("key")` or `map.getOrElse("key", default = 0)` check the [**scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html) - And do yourself a favour and learn at least the basis of **Scala** before using something as big and complex as **Spark**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use filter?

```scala
val myReducedRDD = MappedRDD.reduceByKey(_ + _)

myReducedRDD
  .filter { case (key, value) => key == "hinein" }
  .map { case (key, value) => value } // also can use .map(_._2)
  .foreach(println)


// to assign to val
val result = myReducedRDD
  .filter { case (key, value) => key == "hinein" }
  .map { case (key, value) => value } 
  .collect()(0)
```

Comment: that returns (hinein.,11), how do I then just assign the 11 to a val?